# Publishing dll to bin in live environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I'm working on a asp.net mvc project that is also using umbraco.
I was asked to make some changes to a class that lives in the App_Folder.
I now need to publish the project but the problems is that we are not to sure on the version that is on the live server and the one that lives on the dev server.
While a team fix that version issue, is that way for me to publish the project locally and then just copy the bin folder (for example) to the live server.
I only need to push live the quick change I made to my class.

Is this possible? I don't want to break a live project.

Comment: when you will change the dll, you will see a recycle of app pool, stop and go

Comment: If you don't know what version you are running, stuff might be included in the .dll that you did not expect. What you are asking is whether you can make sure that only 1 class is different in the code used to build the .dll. That's a pretty impossible task unless you start decompiling stuff, etc. I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was trying to avoid starting decompiling. Eventually I manage to get the source code so I can now make my changes.